# What is the best way to populate a multicolmn listview with data in table form, from any sort of database?

Tags: android, database, listview

say i have a database with a table in it, and the table contained data in the following layout:

```
Name         type         difficulty
-------------------------------------
Test1        polo         7
Test2        golf         2
Test3        vw           8
Test4        vectra       100
```

Now imagine that the list goes down to Test100. How would I utilize a listview to show the data in four neat columns with each listview element showing 1 row of the table?
It doesn't have to use sql databases, if it can be done in xml, i can work with that

I have looked around at lots of database tutorials, but i want to use a table that does not have to be added to the device first. So maybe a different format would be better?

Thanks

Comment: >but i want to use a table that does not have to be added to the device first>>> You'll still want to load the data into memory, having parsed it from somewhere (presumably resources).  At that point you might as well put it into a database, so you can use the normal adapter classes.

Comment: ok, the thing is i'm not sure where to start doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While retrieving data, write query accordingly to your required sorting order.

Use [list view](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) with list item of 3 textviews having weights.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of that! I used a multi-column listview and retrieved the data, and put it in a hashmap